# c# - Generating a list of fixtures with the use of random

Tags: c#, list, random

I'm trying to create a list method for storing a list of fixtures. and currently I keep getting an error on the `if (fixtures[i] != lineup)` part of my code and I cant suss out why.I keep getting the following error.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

I don't understand why this is a problem because surely if fixtures[i] is null then it should add lineup to it?

```
        private List<string> GenerateFixtures()
    {
        List<string> fixtures = new List<string>(); // Create a new list to store the games
        while (fixtures.Count < 7) // There can only be 6 possible games
        {
            Random random = new Random(DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond); // Generate a new random
            int home = random.Next(0, 3); // Home team number
            int away = random.Next(0, 3); // Away team number
            if (home == away) // If they are the same teams
            {
                while (home == away) // whilst they are equal to eachother
                {
                    away = random.Next(0, 3); // generate new away team
                }
            }

            string lineup = string.Format("{0} v {1}", home, away); // convert it to a string

            for (int i = 0; i <= fixtures.Count; i++) // whilst i is 0
            {
                if (fixtures[i] != lineup) // if fixtures is not equal to lineup
                    fixtures.Add(lineup); // add it
            }

        } // loop through till it is done
        return fixtures; // then return it
    }
```

I'm also a bit worried, that I am going about creating this the wrong way. I have 4 teams - team 0, 1,2,3 and they should play each other randomly (i'm using random so that its always a different lineup as i plan on using this for other groups).

0 v 1 || 2 v 3 || 2 v 1 || 3 v 0 || 1 v 3 || 0 v 2

Is there a better way to do this?

I have also just noticed that the way that I am doing this will allow 0 v 1 and 1 v 0 to be added to the list as they are different.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Create a list of pairs with no overlaps?  You'd be much better off using a simple algorithm like pigeonholing rather than doing randoms.

Comment: Move the creation of Random outside the loop.   You _might_ get duplicates and it only needs to be created once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first iteration will cause the error since there is no `Fixtures[0]`.

You need some original code that ensures `Fixtures.Count != 0`. If so (first iteration), add in the first lineup:

```
if (Fixtures.Count == 0) {
    Fixtures.Add(lineup);
} else {
    ...
}
```

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

`ArgumentOutOfRangeException` indicates that you are trying to access an array member with an index outside of the array.

On this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= fixtures.Count; i++)
```

You should change `<=` to `<`

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution for the out of bounds error is to remove the = sign in your for loop from the test. You are testing up to count inclusive which is going to always be 1 higher than there are indices.

Change it to

```
for (int i = 0; i < fixtures.Count; i++)
```

As to your other question as if there is a better way to do it, this is how I would approach the problem and address your concerns about duplicates along with fixing the other issues you are having.

```
private List<string> GenerateFixtures(int teamCount, int matchCount)
{
    var teams = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, teamCount));
    var r = new Random();

    var matchups = from t1 in teams
                   from t2 in teams.Where(t => t > t1)
                   select new Tuple<int, int, int>(t1, t2, r.Next());

    var matches = matchups.OrderBy(m => m.Item3)
                          .Take(matchCount)
                          .Select(m => string.Format("{0} v {1}", m.Item1, m.Item2))
                          .ToList();

    return matches;
}
```

The first thing it does is generates a list of teams for use in generating all the permutations of matches possible. The first LINQ query generates all the possible permutations of matches and assigns them to a tuple along with a random number. The next LINQ query orders the matchups by the random number to keep your requirement that the matches be random, then takes the amount of matches you want. It then projects these to the string formatting you are using and puts them in a list.

Not the only way of doing it, and the whole thing could be done in one giant LINQ query if you wanted to but I broke it up just to make it a bit easier to explain.